# how to replace multiple occurrences of `&nbsp; and <br>`

Tags: javascript, regex

how to replace multiple occurrences of `&nbsp; and <br>` at start of the string with javascript regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myString = myString.replace(/^(&nbsp;|<br>)+/, '');
```

... where `/`...`/` denotes a regular expression, `^` denotes start of string, `($nbsp;|<br>)` denotes "`&nbsp;` *or* `<br>`", and `+` denotes "one or more occurrence of the previous expression". And then simply replace that full match with an empty string.