# How to replace all &nbsp; and <br> from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string, let's say:

```
var str = "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

To replace this with an empty string I'm using this regex:

```
str.replace(/^(&nbsp;|<br>)+/, '');
```

This is removing only the first `nbsp;`. The remaining two are still there. Can anyone please help me to remove all the occurrences of `nbsp;` and `<br>` from the string?

Comment: You may have to run it through a loop for multiple passes.

Comment: Or you could simply specify the `g` option in your regex.

Comment: Already answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513848/how-to-remove-nbsp-and-br-using-javascript-or-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437757/how-to-replace-multiple-occurrences-of-nbsp-and-br http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221995/replace-nbsp-with-br http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12454/javascript-replace

Comment: The `^` means start of the sentence. So of course only the first one is removed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `g` flag ("global") within your regular expression to replace *all* matches rather than the first:

```
str.replace(/ <your pattern here> /g, "");
```